# Procfile not found when deploying app to heroku

Tags: php, git, laravel, heroku

When deploying my laravel application to heroku i get a fail of Procfile not found. How do I create this? and what does this file need to have. I can't access the app via the browser because of the 403 forbidden error.

The exact error message when pushing files to heroku:

```
NOTICE: No Procfile, using 'web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2'.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Procfile is a file named Procfile and is a mechanism for declaring what commands are run by your application’s dynos on the Heroku platform.
So you need to create a file on your `public` directory, name it `Procfile` and add the following:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
```

After this save it and upload it to your server.

Comment: The Procfile should be under the project's root and it should configure the document's root which is public directory. More details at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel#creating-a-procfile

Answer (score 6):

Create it with [these commands](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel#creating-a-procfile):

```
echo web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/ > Procfile
git add .
git commit -m "Procfile for Heroku"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following points are important to avoid this error:

1. Create a Procfile in the root directory of your Laravel app. You can either create this from your IDE or through CLI by running the following command:

```
echo "web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/" > Procfile
```

without the quotes.

```
echo web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/ > Procfile
```

2. The name of the file is caseSensitive in `ucfirst` format.
3. You need to push to heroku **master while you are on your local master branch**.

> To push from another local branch, run the following command:

```
git push heroku your-local-branch:master
```

So, if you're pushing from the `local-dev` branch, you should run:

```
git push heroku local-dev:master
```

Comment: Instruction available [here](https://insidert.medium.com/fix-no-procfile-using-web-heroku-php-apache2-for-laravel-on-windows-d0aeeb725784)